# Как задать время в Java со смещением?

Tags: java, дата, localdate

вот у нас есть в БД таблица значений для смещений. Допустим ищем слово "вчера" получаем `shift = -1`, "позавчера" `shift = -2`, "завтра" `shift = +1`;

Задача: к текущей дате присобачить смещение. Да можно сделать

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int offset = date.getDayOfMonth() + shift;
```

потом вернуть что? Можно написать Sout(...вывести), но нужно именно вернуть Дату со смещением

До бишь обратно Int'ы в дату возвращать как то не очень.

Вывод формата: `2023-01-12 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `plusDays`, чтобы получить новую дату, отличающуюся от указанной на заданное количество дней:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int shift = -2;
LocalDate newDate = date.plusDays(shift);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(newDate);
```

Пример вывода:

```
2023-01-13
2023-01-11
```

Если нужно именно в формате со временем, то это по сути уже конвертация `LocalDate` в `LocalDateTime`. Можно использовать метод `.atStartOfDay()` (получить дату-время на полночь указанной даты):

```
System.out.println(date.atStartOfDay());
System.out.println(newDate.atStartOfDay());
```

Вывод:

```
2023-01-13T00:00
2023-01-11T00:00
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.